# Unable to use service using last release of Angular-fullstack generator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-fullstack

I just updated my Angular-fullstack generator from 3.0.0-rc9 to 3.7.0.

I created a new project :

```
yo angular-fullstack myProject
```

I have some trouble when I want to create a new service :

```
yo angular-fullstack:service myService
```

Once it's created, I've got the following **error** on my browser : (this is my problem)

```
angular.js:68
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myProjectApp.myService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

It's correctly inject in the index.html :

```
<script src="app/service/myService/myService.service.js"></script>
```

And here, the content of myService.service.js : (just in case ^^)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myProjectApp.myService')
  .service('myService', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
  });
```

I don't know if it could comes from this : (during bower install)

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) angular#~1.2.0 which resolved to 1.2.29 and is required by ngSweetAlert#1.1.0
    2) angular#~1.2.9 which resolved to 1.2.29 and is required by ng-ckeditor#0.2.1
    3) angular#>=1.4.0 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-bootstrap#1.1.2
    4) angular#^1.2.0 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by ngSmoothScroll#2.0.0
    5) angular#1.5.5 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-animate#1.5.5
    6) angular#~1.5.0 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by webapp2
    7) angular#^1.2.6 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-socket-io#0.7.0
    8) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.18
    9) angular#>=1.2.0 <2.0.0 which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-validation-match#1.5.2
    10) angular#* which resolved to 1.5.5 and is required by angular-clipboard#1.4.2

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 5
```

How to solve it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1863), I removed **.myService** which give me this now :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myProjectApp')
  .service('myService', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
  });
```

It works now !